# cannot access windows azure virtual machine

Tags: windows, azure, azure-virtual-machine

While configuring one of the subnet IP address (for virtual machine in windows azure), deleted Microsoft Virtual Machine Network Bus adapter and now cannot access the Virtual machine via RDP. Before this I was able to RDP into the virtual machine.
Is there an alternate access to the virtual machine?

Comment: I'd suggest contacting support )http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/support/contact to see how they may be able to help.  You *might* be able to download the VHD from blob storage, create a new VM locally in HyperV, patch it and then push it back up, but I haven't tried it and you'll want a fast pipe to download and push it back up.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can always try to use your public IP Adresses of your VM and you can establish a SSH connection with command line. In order to connect in SSH you should take these steps on below.

1. Open your terminal
2. type: ssh  *yourusername@youripadress* ex: *ssh john@192.168.2.3*
3. You will be asked for your *password*

After this you will be able to connect. If not you should authorize the port 22 SSH in your vm machine configuration.

Second solutions:

-Is to use an Azure Bastion.